# Implementation missing for Moments function von openCV

Tags: java, android, opencv

I'm trying to develop an application with android studio to capture the color of flashing LEDs.
Im now at this Point, that i got the positions of the LEDs and now i want to determine the bounding box center with the class moments of openCV.

```
Mat src = new.Mat(Bitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.getWidth(), CvType.CV_8UC1);
Mat hsv = new Mat();

Utils.bitmapToMat(Bitmap, src);
Imgproc.cvtColor(src,hsv, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2HSV);

Core.inRange(hsv,LOWER_RED,HIGHER_RED,hsv);
Imgproc.dilate(hsv,hsv,Imgproc.getStructuringElement(Imgproc.MORPH_VECT,new Size(50,50)));

List<MatOfPoint> contours = new ArrayList <>();
Mat hierarchy = new Mat();

Imgproc.findContours(hsv, contours, hierarchy, Imgproc.RETR_LIST, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
hierarchy.release();

//finding Bounding Box Center
List<Moments> mu = new ArrayList<>(contours.size());
mu.add(1, Imgproc.moments(contours.get(1), false));

Utils.matToBitmap(hsv,Bitmap);

//...
```

And the lines with Moments brings me following error message:

*No implementation found for double[] org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc.moments_0(long, boolean) ( tried Java_org_opencv_imgproc_Imgproc_moments_10 and Java_org_opencv_imgproc_Imgproc_moments_10__JZ )*

So if i jump to Imgproc.java then the method is red marked and following message popups by mouseover:

*Cannot resolve corresponding JNI function Java_org_opencv_imgproc_Imgproc_moments_10
Reports native method declaration in Java where no corresponding JNI functions is found in the project.*

Thanks for reading

Can anyone help me ?

Comment: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/5017

Comment: Thx for your help Miki!

A "new" Release of OpenCv is downloadable.
I don't know why, but the version number is 2.4.13 and smaller than 3.1 
this version works well with moments.

Thanks @ all for your help :)

Have a nice day !